# azure startup shutdown automation

Tags: azure, azure-automation

I'm trying to create start/stop schedule for my virtual machine. Simple schedule:

**Start @ 10am, Stop @ 5pm, don't run on the weekend**

Trying to create this automatic schedule is turning into a nightmare! 
I don't have time to learn PowerShell.

I looked into doing this thru the Automation portal. I have imported a script through the repository.

```
"Name of Script: Scheduled Virtual Machine Shutdown/Startup by Automys"
```

and as it is shown in  Azure portal:

```
"assert-autoshutdownshedule."
```

I now need to edit this script.

Where/how do I input my credentials/parameters? What needs to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

Create Run as Automation account in azure portal
then import the below script to your Runbook.

```
if(-not (@('Saturday', 'Sunday') -contains (Get-Date).DayOfWeek)) #skip execution if the day of week is Saturday or Sunday
{

$cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "Your Automation Account"
Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred
Get-AzureRmSubscription 
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName "Your Subscription Name"

Start-AzureRmVM -Name "VM001" -ResourceGroupName "Your Resource group" -ErrorAction Continue -Force





}
```

All the best :)

Let me know if this work

Comment: Hi, thx, for your response. We have stopped using Azure, but i will definitely, hold on to the instructions, for future purposes.